# Merging two sorted singly linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, merge, linked-list

I came across this problem on Leetcode while looking for some exam practice, and I came up with the following solution:

```
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}

public class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        // base case: if any one of the lists are empty then we are done. 
        if (l1 == null) return l2;
        else if (l2 == null) return l1;

        ListNode head = new ListNode(-1); 
        // dummy head node

        ListNode prev = head; // pointer to do the modifications on the list
        while ((l1 != null) && (l2 != null)) {
            // while both lists arent empty
            int val;
            if (l1.val < l2.val) {
                val = l1.val;
                l1 = l1.next;
            } else {
                val = l2.val;
                l2 = l2.next;
            }
            ListNode curr = new ListNode(val); // creates a new node with the chosen value
            prev.next = curr; // update pointers
            prev = curr;
        }

        // one of the list is finished. we add the rest onto the list ln
        if (l1 == null) prev.next = l2;
        else prev.next = l1;

        return head.next;
    }
}
```

It appears to pass all the tests - however the problem I have is that it is slower than 90% of the solutions submitted. I've recently leanred about linkedlists and I'm still not completely comfortable with the concept, which is why there is probably some lapses in understanding resulting in inefficient code here. I'd be grateful if someone could explain how my implementation can be improved.

Comment: Why do you create new nodes when you just add the rest of the remaining nodes at the end of your method? It seems you don't have to create new nodes and just (re)using the nodes that were passed should give you quite some performance improvement, especially for long lists.

Comment: How can anyone possibly know why your code is slower than some other, unknown code that is a solution to some unspecified problem?

Comment: `null` lists != empty lists. check the `size()` of the lists as well as their null value

Comment: @pvg Well I'm afraid this is as specific as I can get. Here is the original problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/

Comment: You just managed to get more specific so, perhaps it wasn't.

Comment: @pvg I'm glad there has been some clarification. I'm not too sure what crucial part of the problem statement I missed initially.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you very much. The pointer action would get a little bit more complicated from what I can think - do I need to have seperate pointers now for list1 and list2?

Comment: No, you actually don't have to add any additional reference (they're not quite pointers), just directly assign `l1` or `l2` to `curr`. Besides that the execution speed of your solution depends on the server load etc., i.e. if you submit the exact same solution twice you'll probably get different times.

Comment: The question specifically says 'The new list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.'. You are not doing that, you're doing something that takes more time - making new nodes.

Comment: @pvg I see, thank you. That part seemed to have slipped past me whilst I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of juggling pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

First, it works inconsistently with input data. If one of the input lists is empty, the routine returns the other *input list* as a result. On the other hand, if both input lists are non-empty, the routine creates *new items* to build a result list. However, when one of input lists gets exhausted during the merging process, the remaining part of *the other one* is appended to the result list. Eventually the result list is built partially with *new nodes* and a trailing part of one of the input lists.

That causes unnecessary overhead for creating duplicates of nodes and for destroying original nodes, which got replaced with their copies.

To avoid that, buid the result list directly with nodes taken from input lists. No creation of new nodes then, no recycling of old nodes, no intermediate variable to keep `val` before it is copied, no risk you'll forget copying some other data members if the `ListNode` class is ever extended...

The other one is ordering the output nodes. You use the 'less than' operator to decide whether to get the next node from `l1` or from `l2`. That's wrong. You should use 'less than or equal', so for equal keys you get nodes from `l1` first, then from `l2`. This way nodes which have equal key values `val`, but are otherwise distinguishabe (say, they have other data members), maintain the original order. We call it a *stable* sorting.

Implementation:

```
public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {

    ListNode head = new ListNode(-1);  // temporary head node
    ListNode last = head; // the last item of the list; we append here

    while ((l1 != null) && (l2 != null)) { // while both lists arent empty
        if (l1.val <= l2.val) {            // 'or equal' for stable merging
            last.next = l1;                // append the chosen node to result list
            l1 = l1.next;                  // skip (effectively remove) it in input list
        } else {
            last.next = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        last = last.next;                  // the appended node becomes last
    }

    // one of the lists is finished - append the rest of the other one
    if (l1 == null) last.next = l2;
    else last.next = l1;

    return head.next;
}
```

Additionally we don't need testing whether any of input lists is empty – if so, the `while` loop is skipped with no iteration and the last `if` appends the non-empty input list to the result. The gain here is one `if` less at the cost of creating a temporary `head` node.

We can also get rid of the temporary `ListNode` variable at the cost of additional conditional branch. This may be useful when the node class becomes more complicated, as we would potentially have to give more parameters to constructor, which may be unavailable inside the merging routine.

```
public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {

    if (l1 == null) return l2;
    else if (l2 == null) return l1;    // make sure both lists aren't empty

    ListNode head = null;                  // the resulting list's head

    if (l1.val <= l2.val) {                // choose the head node
        head = l1;
        l1 = l1.next;
    } else {
        head = l2;
        l2 = l2.next;
    }

    ListNode last = head;  // the last item of the list; we append here

    while ((l1 != null) && (l2 != null)) { // while both lists arent empty
        if (l1.val <= l2.val) {            // 'or equal' for stable merging
            last.next = l1;                // append the chosen node to result list
            l1 = l1.next;                  // skip (effectively remove) it in input list
        } else {
            last.next = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        last = last.next;                  // the appended node becomes last
    }

    // one of the lists is finished - append the rest of the other one
    if (l1 == null) last.next = l2;
    else last.next = l1;

    return head;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question asked, it's an answer to the exercise.

Comment: @pvg It doesn't answer? OP asked 'if someone could explain how my implementation can be improved'. Well, this is an example, how their implementation can be improved: by avoiding creation of unnecessary objects and relinking input data instead; precisely along the task description: not 'create a new list with merged data' but 'merge input lists' (they say: '[The new list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/#/description)').

Comment: It doesn't explain anything it just drops an implementation, says nothing about how it's better than poster's implementation, why the performance characteristics are different, etc. It's just a blob of code. Which is a bad answer much in the way 'why doesn't this blob of code work' is a flaggable bad question.

Comment: @pvg Perhaps CiaPan could improve the answer by adding more clarifications, however personally I've found this answer to be helpful after digesting the code - which, I suppose served my goal of finding and understanding the reasoning behind a better implementation.

Comment: @user2938375 that's great but the purpose of the site is to collect questions and answers many can find useful, not to adequately answer, for you personally, your specific question. Which is why it has guidelines about what constitute good questions and answers.

Comment: @pvg I believe most people would find this alternative implementation to be a useful answer to this specific question. It encodes and outlines the thought procces required for a better solution. For someone with the same problem as me all that is needed to understand the issue is to read through the code and understand what it is doing.

Comment: @pvg Is it acceptable now (despite being accepted already)...?

Comment: @pvg, are you there? Can you answer the question in the comment above, please?